# API works locally but when published on Azure as APP SERVICES using hybrid connection gives "500 : Internal Server Error" in postman

Tags: c#, sql-server, azure, api, azure-hybrid-connections

We have an API when tested locally using postman it works fine. As we are publishing it on Azure as "App Service" we have used the Azure Hybrid connection. The connection status is connected. After publishing, when we test the API using postman, it gives "500: internal server error" as we are connecting to the on premise Sql-server.

The TCP is enabled on the sql server. The API is working correctly for queries to the Azure Database. Any step we are missing or any configuration is required?

Any guidance will be appreciated.

Note: We are using 2 connection strings, 1 connecting to the Azure Db and the other to the on-premise db.

Comment: How did you configure the Hybrid Connection and how are you calling it? You should use DNS names in both cases, don't use IP addresses, it won't work.

Comment: You have a two port application.  Port 1 is a HTTP connection between client and server.  Port 2 is a connection between server and database.  The error 500 indicates the server made a processing error after the request is sent from client to server.   There can be lots of reasons for the error.  For example if the server tries to write to a file and does not have permission the error will occur.  Or an app is missing on the server that was available when testing locally.  The error can also occur when server is connecting to database.